# Laravel relationship between two tables with two foreign keys

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, eloquent, psql

Hey how can I make relationships between two table.

```
Users: id, email
Notification: id, user_id(id of the logged user), client_id(id of sender)
```

I would like make relationship between users and notifications by user_id and client_id.
Then I will can get all notifications assigned to logged user, and get email of sender users.

I made that:

```
    public function notifications_with_client() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\User', 'App\Models\Notification', 'user_id', 'id', 'client_id');
}
```

But when I using query i got good notifications but with wrong email.
I got email from ralationship id(from users table) == id(from notifications table)

My query

```
$column = 'notifications_with_client';
$value[1] = ['email', 'notifications.id', 'client_id'];
$query->with([$column => function($query) use ($value) {
                      $query->select($value[1]);
                  }]);
```

Someone know what I do wrong?

Comment: I think you need to make many to many relationship?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could post what Model you have this relationship in. And what does `client_id` reference? I assume users. If it does then you indeed have many-to-many relationship.

Comment: You cannot use `$this->hasManyThrough()` for here, use `$this->belongesTo()` as I mentioned in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it by defining the following relations:

`User` Model

```
public function notifications()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Notification');
}
```

`Notification` Model

```
public function to()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
}

public function from()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'client_id');
}
```

And then you can query it as:

```
$notifications = auth()->user()->notifications()->with('from')->get();
```

Or if you just want `email` then query it as:

```
$notifications = auth()->user()
                    ->notifications()
                    ->with(['from' => function($q) {
                        $q->select('email');
                    }])
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Users::class, 'user_id');
}

public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Users::class, 'client_id');
}
```

With this code in your Notification Model you can get the logged user with

```
$this->user(); // $notification->user();
```

and the sender with

```
$this->client(); //$notification->client();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$this->hasManyThrough().` It use for a [different reason](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

You can use `$this->belongsTo()` like this.

```
class User extends BaseModel
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Notification::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Notification::class, 'client_id');
    }
}
```

Then you can query like.

```
User::with(['user']);
```

or

```
User::with(['client']);
```